# Getting Boolean from Getter value according to getter identifier

Tags: jsf

I need to enable/disable a  according to the field of the database "estadopdf".

I got this, but disable all rows:

```
boolean est_habilitado = ord.getEstadopdf() == 1? false:true;
```

And my xhtml:

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" value="PDF" class="icon-file-pdf" 
               actionListener="#{ordenRetiroBean.exportpdf(ord)}"
               disabled="#{ordenRetiroBean.est_habilitado}">
</p:commandLink>
```

I need to make a condition that disable the `<p:commandLink>` from the bean.

The logic i guess, can be

1.- Get the id from that row `ordenRetiroentity.getCod_OrdenRetiro`

2.- ask this `ord.getEstadopdf() == 1? false:true`

3.- return a boolean on my method.

4.- give the boolean to my attribute "disable"

Comment: I tried to understand it but I can't, please show some more code. Do you have a datatable you select a row in? What is ordenRetiroentity, a bean or property or what? What updates ordenRetiroentity.cod_OrdenRetiro?

Comment: I need to check a value on my database that is INT type, according to that value of the row, i want to enable or disable the option for export the pdf on the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "disables all rows" I guess the commandLink is part of for example a datatable row.

So maybe all links are disabled because you're using the managed bean name and not the "var" (which is the row) like in

```
<h:dataTable value="#{userData.employees}" var="employee">
```

Look here for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_display_datatable.htm

You're condition in this example could be

```
disabled="#{employee.disablePdfLink}"
```

In case this doesn't help, please specify your problem more detailed and/or post more code.

Comment: I see that i must be more specific, sorry for my english.

I got on the database a field type int called "estadopdf" that has two values (0 or 1), if is 0, the commandLink must be active, if is 1, the commandLInk must be disabled. 

For this, i got on my entity declared the getter getEstadoPdf as boolean. And i want to do a method that check the value on the database and according to that value, enable o disabled that option on the datatable. (each roch on the datatable has the option exportpdf)